# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, typescript1.8

I have a simple form that is suppose to display error messages

#### errorm-messages.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common'
import {REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'

@Component(
    {
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'epimss-error-messages',
      template: `
   <span class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</span>`,
      styles: [],
      directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgIf]

    })
export class ErrorMessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  ctrlName: string

  constructor(private _form: FormGroup) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      }

  get errorMessage() {
    // Find the control in the Host (Parent) form
    let ctrl = this._form.find(this.ctrlName);

    console.log('ctrl| ', ctrl)

//    for (let propertyName of ctrl.errors) {
//      // If control has a error
//      if (ctrl.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && ctrl.touched) {
//        // Return the appropriate error message from the Validation Service
//        return CustomValidators.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName);
//      }
//    }

    return null;
  }
```

}

Usage

#### language.component.html after import as a directive in language.component.ts

```
<div layout = "column"
     layout-align = "start start">
  <md-input required
            placeholder = "First"
            formControlName = "first"></md-input>
  <epimss-error-messages ctrlName = "first"></epimss-error-messages>
  <md-input placeholder = "Second"
            formControlName = "second"></md-input>
  <!--<epimss-error-messages ctrlName = "second"></epimss-error-messages>-->

</div>
```

Once the line

```
<epimss-error-messages ctrlName = "first"></epimss-error-messages>
```

is present I get the following console error and the UI fails to display:

> EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:4200/app/registration/language/language.component.html:44:2
>       browser_adapter.ts:74 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:4200/app/registration/language/language.component.html:44:2BrowserDomAdapter.logError
>   @ browser_adapter.ts:74BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @
>   browser_adapter.ts:85ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:50(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:396ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:96NgZone.run @
>   ng_zone.ts:211ApplicationRef_.run @
>   application_ref.ts:384ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @
>   application_ref.ts:408(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:150ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:356onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:53ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>       browser_adapter.ts:74 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for FormGroup!BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.ts:74ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:62(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:396ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:96NgZone.run @
>   ng_zone.ts:211ApplicationRef_.run @
>   application_ref.ts:384ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @
>   application_ref.ts:408(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:150ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:356onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:53ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>       browser_adapter.ts:74 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.ts:74ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:66(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:396ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:96NgZone.run @
>   ng_zone.ts:211ApplicationRef_.run @
>   application_ref.ts:384ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @
>   application_ref.ts:408(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:150ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:356onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:53ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>       browser_adapter.ts:74 Error: DI Exception
>           at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (exceptions.ts:13)
>           at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_exceptions.ts:51)
>           at new NoProviderError (reflective_exceptions.ts:84)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:839)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:868)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:830)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:623)
>           at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.ts:15)
>           at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.ts:15)
>           at _View_LanguageComponent0.createInternal (LanguageComponent.template.js:217)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.ts:74ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:67(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:396ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:96NgZone.run @
>   ng_zone.ts:211ApplicationRef_.run @
>   application_ref.ts:384ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @
>   application_ref.ts:408(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:150ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:356onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:53ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>       browser_adapter.ts:74 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:74ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:71(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:396ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:96NgZone.run @
>   ng_zone.ts:211ApplicationRef_.run @
>   application_ref.ts:384ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @
>   application_ref.ts:408(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:150ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:356onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:53ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>       browser_adapter.ts:74 DebugContext {_view: _View_LanguageComponent0, _nodeIndex: 30, _tplRow: 44, _tplCol: 2}BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.ts:74ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:72(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:396ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:96NgZone.run @
>   ng_zone.ts:211ApplicationRef_.run @
>   application_ref.ts:384ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @
>   application_ref.ts:408(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:150ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:64ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:356onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:53ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>       browser_adapter.ts:84 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:4200/app/registration/language/language.component.html:44:2
>   ...

Removing the last code above and the display is as expected.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `disableDeprecatedForms(),  provideForms()` in `bootstrap()`?

Comment: Yes - the app was working fine.

Comment: @st_clair_clarke did you find a solution for this? I'm experiencing this error as in a custom component I have with a c'tor like `constructor(@Host() formModel: FormGroup) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to inject FormGroup, just use it as a class and instantiate it directly.

So your constructor should be just

```javascript
constructor() {
    this._form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl('value')
    })
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the FormGroup in the constructor is suppose to be that of the parent form. I then use this FormGroup to find the FormControl to display the error message. So, it is NOT really an injection so much. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working in my case, quite similar to yours:

```ts
import { FormGroupDirective, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

//...

constructor(@Host() private hostFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {
}

// ...

get errorMessage() {
  // Find the control in the Host (Parent) form
  const ctrl: NgControl = this.hostFormGroup.directives
    .find(dir => dir.name === this.ctrlName);
  // ...
}
```

I'm not sure if there are cleaner ways, but this seems good at the moment.